# How to add client id to Google Drive Client API for Java

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I'm just getting started with using the Google Drive REST API in an Android app. (I can't use the [Google Drive API for Android](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/) because the app needs to share files, and perhaps a few other things, that GDAA doesn't support.) I'm stuck on a couple of points.

The first has to do with OAuth2.0 credentials. I went through the [Android quick start example](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android) and it works fine. I set up a project on my Google developer console and generated an OAuth2.0 client ID and secret and also downloaded the JSON credentials file. However, the quick start example doesn't show how to plug any of this into the app. The only thing I found in the docs that seems relevant is [`GoogleClientSecrets`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleClientSecrets), but I don't see anything about how to use that in an Android app. (The [Java quick start example](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java) uses this, but it's not integrated with Android's account manager and doesn't seem right for an Android app.) When I run the Android version of the quick start app, no activity shows up on my developer console, which suggests to me that the app is running in some sort of anonymous mode. As I understand it, that would limit the app to a very low daily quota of transactions.

Second, I noticed that the GDAA and the REST API for JavaScript both have nice file picker APIs. I couldn't find anything similar in the Java/Android API.

So here are my specific questions:

- How do I use my app's OAuth2.0 credentials from the developer console in a REST API for Android Java app? I feel like I'm just missing something obvious.
- Is there a file picker API for the Google Rest API for Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After stepping through the library as I executed the Quickstart example (a painful process, as there is no source code), I discovered the answer. It turns out that you need to specify the client ID in the manifest. Specifically, you needs the following under the `<application>` tag:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.app.id"
    android:value="app ID from your API console"/>
```

Once this entry is in the manifest, then when the app uses the Google Drive REST API to interact with Google's servers, the transaction is correctly logged as traffic in your app's console. Without this entry, the app seemed to work in my testing, but no traffic was logged. I seem to recall (from an old Google I/O video) that such "anonymous" apps still work, but have a very low usage quota (something like 10 or 100 queries/day).

For those who are curious, I found this key in the class `com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzz`, found in the `play-services-basement-10.2.0` library.

Answer (score 1):

Save the client_id.json file downloaded from the Google API console into into your  app's src/main/res directory.

I was stuck exactly the same, but after I built my app with the file included the Google API started working.

Comment: thank you so much! I had this problem with Google Fit API and I can't understand why it is not indicated anywhere to do that. fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

**How do I use my app's OAuth2.0 credentials from the developer console in a REST API**

The pages around https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client give you all that you need to know. In particular, note the Java Quickstart you were using is for generic Java. The way Google Play Services on Android manage credentials and accounts is very Android-specific.

**Is there a file picker API for the Google Rest API for Android?**

Not that I know of, but depending on your use case, you might be able to use the GDAA picker. Ultimately, both GDAA and the Java REST API are layers above your Drive storage.

Comment: The Java Quickstart I was using was not for generic Java; it was specifically the REST Quickstart for Android. There's a separate generic Java Quickstart [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java). The pages you pointed me to still don't answer my question. What do I do with the client ID generated through my developer console? There's no place in any of the docs (that I can find) on where that info goes in my app. Regarding mixing REST with the GDAA picker: is there a risk that the app will prompt twice for permission to access the user's drive?

Comment: Did you read https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth in conjunction with Steps 1 and 2 from the Android Quickstart link you posted? The point is that Client auth for Android apps that use Play Services to manage the auth dialogue don't use client-IDs in the same way that (say) a generic Java or php app would.

Comment: Yes, I read that. It explains how to register my signing certificate in the developer console, but it doesn't say how to use the API key that the console generates. That's where I'm stuck. The plain Java version of the REST Quickstart shows how to read in a JSON file to get this information, but the Android REST Quickstart doesn't show anything like this. I guess I'm looking for something that would go into the manifest, like what one would do with the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start#api-key). Are you saying that this just isn't needed for Drive?

Comment: For Android credentials, the client ID is bound to the package signature in the API Console, therefore there is no need for it to be installed within the app or manifest. Simply by virtue of the calls coming from myapp.example.com, Google knows the client ID. This is all assuming that you are using Play Services for the Auth flow. If you're rolling your own (definitely not recommended), then you'll be using it just as you would in a generic Java app.

Comment: When the app is credentialed solely based on the package signature as you describe, app traffic does not seem to appear in my developer's API console. When the client ID is embedded in the manifest (as I describe in my answer) then the traffic is logged. If things are as you describe, what explains this difference?